# BoxCars Java Program - Beginner. Weird Issue: Program doesn't run in the console but, it lists no errors in Eclipse

Tags: java

I wrote this code in Eclipse Java and for some reason, it doesn't run. It doesn't say it has any errors in it and no red marks appear anywhere in the code. I'm not sure what is wrong with it, please help.

Here is the description of what I needed to write: Design and implement a class called PairOfDice, composed of two six-sided Die objects. Create a driver class called BoxCars with a main method that rolls a PairOfDice object 1000 times, counting the number of boxcars (two sixes) that occur.

Another issue I have is creating "two six-sided Die objects" in the PairOfDice class. I don't have it written in the code, so if someone could explain how to implement those objects I would appreciate it.

The last issue I'm having is making a driver class (BoxCars). I have tried to look up what exactly was a driver class but I couldn't find anything that I could understand.

```
public class dieGames {

    public class PairOfDice {

       private int die1; 
       private int die2;

       public PairOfDice() {
           roll();
       }

       public void roll() {
          die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
          die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
       }

       public int getValueDie1() {
          return die1;
       }

       public int getValueDie2() {
          return die2;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return "Die 1: " + die1 + ", Die 2: " + die2;
       }
    }

    public class BoxCars
    {
       public void main(String[] args)
       {
          final int numRolls = 1000;
          int numBoxCars = 0;

          PairOfDice twoDice = new PairOfDice();

          for (int i = 0; i < numRolls; i++)
          {
             twoDice.roll();
             if (twoDice.die1 == 6 && twoDice.die2 == 6)
             {
                numBoxCars++;
             }
          }

          System.out.println("Number of Box Cars in " + numRolls +
                             " rolls is " + numBoxCars);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I'm having issues getting the program to run_" What issues exactly? You didn't tell us what the problem or error is.

Comment: *"I'm not exactly sure what is wrong"* - Why do you believe that something is wrong?  Are you observing a specific problem of some kind?

Comment: There are no marked issues in Java Eclipse so I have no idea what is wrong with it

Comment: So then what makes you say it is not working?

Comment: Homework question with actual attempt. That is rare so I need to congratulate you! But still for better help we need to know more about *specific* problem you are facing. Homework taks isn't for you to get some code, but to let you learn how to create it. If you are facing some problem with some specific step please [edit] your question and describe it in more detail.

Comment: @takendarkk I'm not sure but its an issue with the classes and the way I set them up. I have to make a driver class (BoxCars) and maybe I didn't do something right there. But the program just doesn't run in the console.

Comment: @AshwatthaShinde: Can you elaborate on "just doesn't run"?  How specifically do you *try* to run the program and what specifically *happens*?

Comment: "_There are no marked issues in Java Eclipse_" That is not true for me. When I put this code in Eclipse is shows errors. You have `twoDice.die1` but `die1` is a private field so you cannot access it like that.

Comment: "it just doesn't run in the console" well code doesn't run by itself, it needs some trigger, some action which will start it. How do *you* try to run it?

Comment: The only error that is there is that I purposely added "static" in the main method for BoxCars because I  saw that, I needed to include that. Originally I removed that and there were no red marks, but the program wouldn't run in the console.

Comment: Also are you sure you posted this code correctly because currently your `public class BoxCars` is *inside* `public class PairOfDice` which probably isn't desired situation. You are also not using `getValueDie1()` and `getValueDie2()` methods but trying to access `die1` and `die2` instead.

Comment: I press the green circle with the triangle in it to run the program

Comment: Well, based on the code you posted, the code will not run because it will not compile because there are errors you have not fixed.

Comment: Yeah its some issue with my classes, I think. It might make more sense what im trying to do if you read the assignment. Im sorry if im making this too confusing

Comment: It is not an issue with classes and we don't even need to understand the assignment. The problem is you tried to access a private field like it was not private and that is not valid java. The issue is not specific to your current task.

Comment: I asked someone else on stackoverflow this question but I wasn't able to understand their explanation for the driver class (BoxCars). I asked them about it, but I didn't receive a response, so I thought I would ask the question again.

Comment: Im going to use a different code that I used before to see if it makes more sense. Just hold on one second.

Answer (score -2):

Why is BoxCars inside the PairOfDice class? They should be seperated files. Also the assignment says something about 'Die objects', which makes me question where your Die class is.

The code itself looks like it should work and should give the correct answer though (I haven't tried it to run).